# Download files from different directories with wildcards using wget?

Tags: wget

I need to download all files with "h11v10" in the name from a http server, from different directories (`DF`). I tried different ways but none of them worked.

```
wget --http-user user --http-password pass \
  'https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD16A2.006/DF/*h11v10*'

wget --http-user user --http-password pass \
  -r -l1 --no-parent -A 'h11v10' \
  'https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD16A2.006/DF/'
```

How can I deal with different directories and wildcards using `wget`? I also tried  `curl` but it did not work either.

Comment: You would have to download a directory listing, parse it, and then fetch the files.

Comment: There is no support in HTTP for wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need a login to download the files, I can't test it for your situation.

So another example: if you want to download all files containing “SHA” from the directories here:

https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-builds/

you can use:

```
wget -r --no-parent 'https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-builds/' --accept '*SHA*'
```

So for your problem, it *should* be:

```
wget -r --no-parent --http-user user --http-password pass \
  'https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD16A2.006/' --accept '*h11v10*'
```

Does that work?

It's not very efficient since it has to download the `index.html` pages first.